# Derivation: Entropy of Vaporisation using Redlich-Kwong EoS

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, chemical-engineering, energy

[image]

The part I'm stuck on is the last part. Basically, the question is to obtain the following equation for the entropy of vaporisation using the Redlich-Kwong equation:
$$
\Delta S = R\Bigg[ \ln \frac{V_2 -b}{V_1 - b} \Bigg] + \frac{0.5a}{bT^{1.5}}\ln \Bigg[ \frac{V_2(V_1-b)}{V_1(V_2-b)} \Bigg]
$$

Solution Attempt:

I think I should start by using the known fact that at equilibrium, the free energy of both phases must be the same. Using Gibbs free energy:
$$
dG = -SdT + VdP \implies -S_1dT + V_1dP = -S_2dT + V_2dP
$$
Therefore, I can write an equation for change in entropy due to vaporisation:
$$
S_1 - S_2 = (V_1 - V_2)\frac{dP}{dT}
$$
However when I simply differentiate the given EoS and multiply by $V_1 - V_2$ I don't get the same result. Clearly, in the answer they have integrated wrt v at some point but I just don't get why or how. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arrived to an answer very similar to what it says it should end up being except for a difference in the sign of a term.

Here is how I proceeded:

The total differential of a two-variable function can be written as
$$ dS(T,V) = \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right) _V dT + \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right) _T dV  $$

Since a phase change occurs at constant temperature, $ dT = 0 $. Hence, the equation becomes simply

$$ 
dS = \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right) _T dV
$$

Replacing the right hand side of the above equation using other thermodynamic relations for the partial derivative in terms of $ P $ and $ T $, we get

$$ 
 dS = \left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T} \right) _V dV
$$

Now we differentiate $ P $ with respect to $T$ at constant $V$:
$$
 \left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T} \right) _V = \frac{R}{V-b} + \frac{a}{2T^{3/2}} \frac{1}{V(V+b)}
$$

Noting that $ \Delta S = \int dS $,

$$
 \Delta S = S_2 - S_1 
= \int_{V_1}^{V_2}  \left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T} \right) _V dV \\
= \left[  R \ln (V-b) +  \frac{a}{2b T^{3/2}} \ln  \left( \frac{V}{V+b} \right) \right]_{V_1}^{V_2} \\
=  R \ln \frac{(V_2-b)}{(V_1 - b)} +  \frac{a}{2b T^{3/2}} \ln  
\left[
\frac{V_2}{V_1} \left( \frac{V_1+b}{V_2+b} \right) \right]
$$

Either the question is wrong in their signs or I made a mistake with the signs in my solution. Either way, this should hopefully guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Note also the discussion at [the other place](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/325691/derivation-entropy-of-vaporisation-using-redlich-kwong-eos/325840).